# Spark Streaming with Kakfa

Tags: scala

I am trying to do spark streaming using Kafka as my source but i am getting error as below :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/protocol/SecurityProtocol;)V

My Kafka version is Kafka_2.11-0.11 and i am using spark 2.0.0 with scala 2.11. I am not able to find the above compatible jar in maven or anywhere. The above mention jar is available with lower version but not with the above configuration. 
I am running the code using SCALA IDE with scala library as 2.11.8. This code ran once successfully but dont know after re-running the code throws the above error.

It will very much helpful if you all can share your ideas and provide some solution. Thanks and advance. Kindly respond !!

Hoping to get answer !!!

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Comment: Yes Cary i have installed java version "1.8.0_131

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
//import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import Utilities._

import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
object KafkaExampleOwn {

Comment: The full code i am not able to paste here , if you can provide your mail id i can share the code..

Comment: can you edit the question and add it?

Comment: val topicSet: String = "spark-topic-new"
    val kafkaParams = Map[String,String]("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(20))
   
    //set(topicSet) is used to read only messages from one topic
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
    ssc, kafkaParams, Set(topicSet))

    val result = messages.map(_._2)
    result.print()
    // Kick it off
    ssc.checkpoint("C:/checkpoint/")
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}

Comment: Its asking for indentation for code if i am editing the question. i pasted the code in two parts ...or else any communicator you want me to connect by which i can share my code, you can let me know. Thanks for the resoponse ...

Comment: Any Help Cary Shindell ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you don't have a main method. Certain languages like java and c require you to have a main method and put your code in it. That's why it's saying `"main": no such method"`. So you'll need to create a main method for everything except import statements, functions, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment !! But i believe i have used the main method in my scala code as : def main(args: Array[String]) {

Comment: It's very difficult to solve without the code. You should be able to paste it into the question, as long as you put 4 spaces in front of each line.

Comment: I understand your problem ! But apologize that i tried adding 4 spaces still it did now allow me to add the code ...

Comment: I just edited and it worked fine. You have to make sure to leave an extra line and put 4 spaces before each line of code.

Comment: Thanks Cary !! I will work on the same from next time as you suggested !!